# I can't install any programs

Tags: software-installation, authentication

So I can't install any programs. Everytime I try to install something a window pops up saying that I need to authorize the install by entering my password. I was told by a friend who knows much more about this kind of thing than I do to enter my crypt-key the one I use to log in and I've tried that over and over again but it still won't work. What do I do?

Comment: Ask root i.e., sudo password, ask password who installed that system or the owner of the system.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that begins with the word `sudo` is going to ask for authentication. You can think of this as a safety measure, because a lot of things that require `sudo` can be messed up by someone who doesn't know what they're doing. Or, if you're not using the terminal, anything that accesses these same essential files should ask for a password. Anyway, point is, it should be your Ubuntu password (not the same as the crypt-key you enter when you boot if you have an encrypted hard-drive). This is the password you enter to log in once the computer is booted up, and probably every time you wake it up from suspended mode.